# Pandas , extract a date from a string value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which contains a column (SecurityPassDate).
example data :

```
"applied on 11/10/2021. need to follow up on 01/12/2021"
"completed on 19/10/2021. need to renew on 01/12/2022"
"applied on 01/12/2021."
```

I want to create a new column(s) in the dataframe which extracts the dates from the free text.

I'm trying to use datefinder to do the work.

example code i am trying:

```
df.loc[:, 'SECURITY INTERVIEW DATE'] = df['SECURITY PASS DATE'].apply(lambda x: df.find_dates(x['SECURITY PASS DATE']))
```

the output i want to see is :

```
"applied on 11/10/2021. need to follow up on 01/12/2021", "11/10/2021", "01/12/2021"
"completed on 19/10/2021. need to renew on 01/12/2022", "19/10/2021", "01/12/2022"
"applied on 01/12/2021.", "01/12/2021"
```

How can I get this working?
Getting the error:

> String indices must be integers

Comment: Please you code blocks to distinguish and format your code. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Do you want both "11/10/2021" and "01/12/2021" in a single column called "SECURITY INTERVIEW DATE"?

Comment: if its possible to get each date in a separate column, or just take the first date it finds.

Comment: getting new message now : expected string or buffer

Comment: fixed it.
i changed the data type of the column to astype('str')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you want:

```
df["SECURITY INTERVIEW DATE"] = df["SECURITY PASS DATE"].apply(lambda x: list(datefinder.find_dates(x)))

>>> df
                                  SECURITY PASS DATE                     SECURITY INTERVIEW DATE
0  applied on 11/10/2021. need to follow up on 01...  [2021-11-10 00:00:00, 2021-01-12 00:00:00]
1  completed on 19/10/2021. need to renew on 01/1...  [2021-10-19 00:00:00, 2022-01-12 00:00:00]
2                             applied on 01/12/2021.                       [2021-01-12 00:00:00]
```

###### Input df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"SECURITY PASS DATE": ["applied on 11/10/2021. need to follow up on 01/12/2021",
                                          "completed on 19/10/2021. need to renew on 01/12/2022",
                                          "applied on 01/12/2021."]})
```

Comment: expected string or buffer

Comment: No idea what you mean by that comment.

Comment: thats the error i got

Comment: It works on the example I posted. No idea why it doesn't work for you. Edit your question to include a sample of your dataframe i.e., the output of `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: sample data from the column:
14/09/2021 @ 11:30am
20/09/2021 @ 11:00am
09/11/2021
need appointment next week
16/11/2021
Will be available on 22/11/2021 to see me
need
12/11/2021
17/11/2021
17/11/2021

sorry its messy, cant format it in newlines

Comment: fixed it. i changed the data type of the column to astype('str').
the column type must have been something suspect.

Answer (score 1):

I'd exctract first and convert then in your case.

```
df['SECURITY PASS DATE']= df['SECURITY PASS DATE'].str[-10:]
pd.to_datetime(df['SECURITY PASS DATE'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would propose

```
# Extract dates as list
date_list = df['SECURITY INTERVIEW DATE'].apply(lambda x: list(datefinder.find_dates(x)))

# build a complementary dataframe where each column as a date
## build the dataframe, creating columns for the row lists items
df_dates = pd.DataFrame(date_list.tolist())
## rename the columns
df_dates = df_dates.set_axis(['date_'+ str(i+1) for i in df_dates.columns], axis=1)

## concat the original dataframe with the complementary one
df = pd.concat([df, df_dates], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                            SECURITY INTERVIEW DATE      date_1      date_2
0 applied on 11/10/2021. need to follow up on 01...  2021-11-10  2021-01-12
1 completed on 19/10/2021. need to renew on 01/1...  2021-10-19  2022-01-12
2                             applied on 01/12/2021  2021-01-12         NaT
```